# Delegate is getting reset to nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `NewCartViewController` that's embedded in a `UINavigationController`

In my `ContainerViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToCart" {
        self.cartVC = segue.destination as? NewCartViewController
        self.cartVC?.delegate = self

        print("cartVC Delegate", cartVC?.delegate) // value is NOT nil here

        let pendingCart = PendingCart(color: .blue)

        self.cartVC?.setupPaintOrder(cart: pendingCart)
    }
}
```

In my `NewCartViewController`

```
protocol NewCartViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func vcDidFinishWithCancel(_ newCartViewController: NewCartViewController)
}

class NewCartViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: NewCartViewControllerDelegate?

    ....

    @objc func dismissVC() { // called from the leftBarButtonItem
        print(delegate) // nil
    }
```

I've looked at other answers that are related but I'm not sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit - more detail on how the VC is instantiated:**

My `BuyButtonVC` calls a delegate method back to `AddToCartContainerVC`:

```
extension AddToCartContainerViewController: BuyButtonViewControllerDelegate {
    func buyButtonVCDidPressButton(_ vc: BuyButtonViewController) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCart", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Which then fires the `prepare(for segue:)` function from the first code block above where the we look at the the `segue.destination` and set the delegate.

I have a print on the `didSet` on the delegate in my `NewCartViewController` and I see that the delegate is set.

The user goes to the screen, the `didSet` is never called again as if it was getting set to `nil`. But then when I try to call the delegate method in the second code block, the delegate is nil

Comment: I'm guessing that the delegate has been deallocated by the time `dismissVC` is called. Is the delegate some other view controller that got dismissed or something like that?

Comment: Nope. The only place this delegate is used is on the presented VC

Comment: Since delegate is weak, if the cartVC is deallocated, the delegate becomes nil -- is it possible your nav stack removed the cartVC?

Comment: You might want to double-check how you initiated the transition to `NewCartViewController`. For example, if the transition was initiated from a push of a button, make sure you didn’t accidentally have both the segue action plus a redundant `@IBAction`. It’s one or the other. We need details on how you instantiated the segue. But the above is not, itself, enough to manifest the problem.

Comment: @Mocha no, the screen in question with the delegate is still the only thing visible to the user so it's definitely not deallocated

Comment: @Rob I added more info

Comment: @ZackShapiro I think you misunderstood Rob a bit. What we need to know is how you defined your segue, I assume you did that in your storyboard. While your additions show you execute `performSegue` programmatically (so I assume ultimately that's triggered by an `IBAction` as Rob guessed) it's unclear whether the segue might also be connected to the button in the storyboard (rather than just to the `ContainerViewController `as it should be in such a case). Having the wrong segue type could also be an issue.

Comment: Re-reading your text again, I am also suspicious about how you set up `ContainerViewController` in general. You write that `NewCartViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, but that's a weird way to put it, I'd have said something like "`ContainerViewController` is the root view controller of my `UINavigationController`". Your container view controller is also embedded in the navigation controller, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the following code and seems to work fine.

Few times we get this unknown behavior and is frustrating when stuck. Try to clean build and quit Xcode clear derived data and do it again.

```swift
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, NewViewControllerDelegate {

    weak var cartVC: NewViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToCart" {
            self.cartVC = segue.destination as? NewViewController
            self.cartVC?.delegate = self

            print("cartVC Delegate", cartVC?.delegate) // value is NOT nil here

//            let pendingCart = PendingCart(color: .blue)

//            self.cartVC?.setupPaintOrder(cart: pendingCart)
        }
    }

    func vcDidFinishWithCancel(_ newViewController: NewViewController) {
        print(newViewController.delegate)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}

protocol NewViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func vcDidFinishWithCancel(_ newViewController: NewViewController)
}


class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: NewViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))
    }

    @objc func dismissVC() { // called from the leftBarButtonItem
        print(delegate) // nil
        delegate?.vcDidFinishWithCancel(self)
    }
}
```

Output: when leftbarbuttonitem clicked

```
cartVC Delegate Optional(<NetworkExtensionTest.ViewController: 0x7f84c6d07670>)
Optional(<NetworkExtensionTest.ViewController: 0x7f84c6d07670>)
Optional(<NetworkExtensionTest.ViewController: 0x7f84c6d07670>)
```

Comment: in your `NewViewController` you never call the delegate method

Comment: @ZackShapiro updated the code but not getting nil. working properly.
Just confirming though if your prepareForSegue is being called properly.
I was getting nil when I did set wrong class in Storyboard (`ViewController` instead of `ContainerViewController`)